# How to handle prospective change of job

Tags: software-industry, job-change, germany

Related to my question [Changing Jobs shortly after expensive training](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/157862/changing-jobs-shortly-after-expensive-training)

I am looking for advise on how to handle the following Situation.

I will change my current employment, this will probably be very soon interviewing has been good but slow to the current situation but might happen later.

I and another coworker will receive Training within the next 2 weeks. I am looking for a solution without revealing that i am looking for a new job, on how to handle the training.

One option i could think off would be turning in a sick notice, this training is dated so not reschedulable.
Another one would be telling them i dont feel up to the task of dealing with this, hardly doubt this will do.

I would prefer to not burn bridges.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't a lot of good options here.

It may be too late already: You can't just cancel an expensive training on short notice and expect a full refund. You would have to find out what the terms of the training contract are: the company may be able to send someone else or get a partial refund, but it's unlikely that all expenses can be saved if you simply don't go (for whatever reason).

In order to figure this out, you'd have to ask about the terms which of course will trigger the question: "why do you want to know?".

I recommend against making up a fake story or pretending you are sick. Don't lie. It rarely ends well, it's ethically wrong and it burns more bridges than anything else.

In this case your best shot is to go through with the training and deal any fallout when you have landed a new job and are ready to resign. They won't be happy, but it's also "just business" and not the end of the world. You are still behaving professionally.

The only alternative would be to have an open conversation with your manager ASAP. I would ONLY consider this if you really really trust your manager and leadership and if you are highly confident you can land a new job relatively soon.